# Center views horizontally of different widths inside a UIStackView

Tags: ios, uiview, uikit, uistackview

I would like to setup a UIViewStack so that it will center the two views inside, even though they have different widths. Here is an example:

[image: example]

Is it possible to achieve this type of configuration with UIStackView? I cannot seem to figure it out!

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

You should use nested `StackView`. Firstly embed View1 and View2 in a `Horizontal StackView`. Set alignment property center and distribution fill-proportionally. Then embed the `Horizontal StackView` in a `Vertical Stackview`. Here I have attached my demo screenshot: [image]

Answer (score 2):

No , you can't . From the apple's Doc

> The stack view uses Auto Layout to position and size its arranged views. The stack view aligns the first and last arranged view with its edges along the stack’s axis. **`In a horizontal stack, this means the first arranged view’s leading edge is pinned to the stack’s leading edge, and the last arranged view’s trailing edge is pinned to the stack’s trailing edge.`**

You can use **Constraints** instead.

Answer (score 1):

I can make UIStackView auto grow width after adding views there

1. Create UIViewController and give UIStackView be center there
   [image]
2. Constraint
   StackView.leading Priority set to 250 to avoid warning issue in xib
   [image]
3. Codes

   class StackSampleViewController: UIViewController {

   ```
   @IBOutlet weak var stackView: UIStackView!

   //Keep center auto grow with subviews
   @IBAction func touchUpAdd(_ sender: Any) {
       let view = UIView()
       view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
       view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20.0).isActive = true

       if (stackView.subviews.count % 2) == 0 {
           view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
           view.backgroundColor = .black
       } else {
           view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
           view.backgroundColor = .red
       }

       stackView.addArrangedSubview(view)
   }
   ```

   }
4. Result
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, firstly you create main vertical stackview and set aligment center and distribution fill. Then you create second horizontal stackview in main stack and set alignment and distribition fill. Add the last elements you want to add Thats it.

First stackview:
[image: First stackview]

Second stackview:
[image: second stackview]